# Problems with Velocity Resource Path

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, velocity

So, here's the deal.

I'm using **Spring Framework** to develop a appointment app.

Everything's **going fine** in my **localhost**, **even the email send part**.

But when i pass the project to my **weblogic**, the **resource.loader.path** property appears not to load.

Here's the important part of my code:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
prop.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
prop.setProperty("class.resource.loader.path", "../jsp/email-templates");

VelocityEngine.init(prop);
Template template = VelocityEngine.getTemplate("user-response.jsp");
```

As i said, just the important part of my code. Basically is configured like this with a **Properties Object** and the **VelocityEngine.getTemplate()** loading the **user-response.jsp** file that are inside the folder mentioned above.

As i said, in my localhost, he just works fine but in weblogic appears that way:

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource '..nulluser-response.jsp'
```

For some reason, the **class.resource.loader.path** property do not load in **weblogic**.

So... someone has already been through this problem? Any ideias of what's wrong?

**Obs.: The two projects *(localhost and weblogic)* are the same, using a version control software *(bazaar)***

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend making it relative to the CLASSPATH.  If you put the /email-templates folder under WEB-INF/classes and make the load path "email-templates" it should work.

Comment: Yes, it means you don't know how CLASSPATH works.  Put the Velocity JAR in your WEB-INF/lib.